# How cleared issues in the issues.liferay.com can be applied in our Liferay Portal

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-velocity, liferay-aui

I want to know how to apply the issue changes done in the [Liferay Issues](https://issues.liferay.com) can be applied in our portal.

For example my issues are cleared in the following links,

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-14417?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-14220?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

I want to apply the issue changed in the above links in my portal.

Please some one help me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards, 
Dinesh M K

Answer (score 0):

You have to see the resolution and fix version stated.

- the second issue says :

  Fix Version/s: --Sprint 12/11, 6.1.0 CE RC1
  and that means that the issue was solved in all Portals after version 6.1.0 CE.
- the first issue , is no longer reproducible, and duplicate of https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-14220 which is again solved in 6.1.0 CE RC1

In other words, If your portal is older than this version, you can't do anything. You'll have to upgrade to version 6.1.0 RC1 or later

Comment: Hi,
I am using Liferay Portal 6.1.1 CE GA2.

But I think the issue is not fixed. The Due Date in the Kaleo Workflow is doing nothing after the time given in the Due Date field is expired.

Can you please check and say is it working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using 6.1.1 ga2, and I have no time to test now. As Olaf says, the fix will be available in 6.2, so it's quite normal you can't see it fixed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the fixed-in version is a bit weirdly set in those issues - e.g. LPS-14220 is a subtask of a story in LPS-14414, which is stated as completed for 6.2.0. Careful: I did not fully read through all of the issue's descriptions, links and mix what I read with the answer (and comment to) @yannicuLar gave

Basically, this seems to be a new feature. The way to backport it to your installation is to identify the relevant commits (e.g. download the repository from https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal or https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins, identify the relevant commits (they all contain the LPS number), "backport" them (e.g. see if they can just be applied to your codebase or if they need manual adaptation because the whole code changed.

Some features are easier to backport than others, I can't tell about the complexity for this one.

In order to separate your changes from Liferay's core changes, you should try to implement this in plugins (or patched plugins) rather than changing the original code and recompile. Most likely it's only the kaleo-web plugin that's effected, but if there are core changes, you'd be better of having them isolated in plugins.

The simplest (and most futureproof) possibility is to wait a bit for 6.2 (RCs are already out) and upgrade your portal to this version. If you want to stay on a version that gets updates, you should do this soon anyway.